# Greek Leters in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, visual-studio-2019

I am writing a simple C# console application to which uses the Greek lowercase Eta (η) to store a specific constant.  I need to be able to print η to the screen with Console.WriteLine("η");

When I attempt:

```
Console.WriteLine("Variable one is **η** \nEnter the value of the second variable");
```

The output is:

```
Variable one is **?**
Enter the value of the second variable
```

Visual Studio 2019 is replacing the η with a question mark.  I've tried using Unicode saved to a char type variable instead of the actual typed η to no avail.  It still uses a question mark.

Does anyone know what I'm missing to generate the correct text output?

Comment: You're generating text output fine; the Windows console uses some old code page that does not include Greek letters; you have to change it or use PowerShell; consult [Change Default Code Page of Windows Console](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/).